# How can I find an object in JPA by its Composited Key ID

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, composite-key

Im trying to find one object from my DB table Real_States which goes like this:

```
CREATE TABLE REAL_STATES (
address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
admin_id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
resident_id VARCHAR(15),
real_state_type_id INT(6) NOT NULL,
block VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
internal_id INT(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (address, block, internal_id),
FOREIGN KEY (real_state_type_id) REFERENCES REAL_STATE_TYPES (real_state_type_id),
FOREIGN KEY (admin_id) REFERENCES ADMINS (admin_id),
FOREIGN KEY (resident_id) REFERENCES RESIDENTS (resident_id)
);
```

And I want to get a row of this table by its composite Primary Key (address, block, internal_id), all this from my EntityManager. This goes like this:

```
public RealState findRealState(RealStateID realStateId) {
    RealState realState = em.find(RealState.class, realStateId); // first Try, which failed
    List<RealState> realStates = em.createQuery("FROM RealState rs WHERE  rs.realStateID.address like :" + realStateId.getAddress()).getResultList(); // second try which failed too
    for (RealState realState2 : realStates) {
        System.out.println(realState2.toString());
    }
    if (realState == null) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException("Can't find realState for ID " + realStateId.toString());
    }
    return realState;
}
```

The RealStateID Class is declared like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class RealStateID  implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6485406412363395170L;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "block")
    private String block;
    @Column(name = "internal_id")
    private int internal_id;
    //getters..setters..
```

But Im just getting error by error, IDK what I am doing wrong, and I would like to figure out it. Im not using Spring, just JPA Hibernate and Java.

Answer (score 0):

As it's stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite):

> The primary key class must define `equals` and `hashCode` methods, consistent with equality for the underlying database types to which the primary key is mapped.

Assuming it, the method:

```java
RealState realState = em.find(RealState.class, new RealStateID(...));
```

should work as expected.

**EDIT** Your `RealStateID` should look like this:

```java
@Embeddable
public class RealStateID  implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6485406412363395170L;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "block")
    private String block;

    @Column(name = "internal_id")
    private int internal_id;`
    
    // getters, setters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;

        RealStateID pk = (RealStateID) o;
        return Objects.equals(address, pk.address) &&
                Objects.equals(block, pk.block) &&
                Objects.equals(internal_id, pk.internal_id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(address, block, internal_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just runned and when I filled the jsp values with "A302", "A1" and "302" it gave me the next error:
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException Can't find realState for ID RealStateID [address=A302, block=A1, internal_id=302]

Which cannot be possible since I have that row in my table Real_States in the BD

Comment: Please show full implementation of your `RealStateID` class

Comment: As you asked, i've edited the question with the implementation of RealStateID

Comment: Does your `RealStateID` class have defined `equals`, `hashCode` like in my updated answer?

Comment: No it did not have them, but now the error has changed to Exception handling request to /ProyectoSw/FindRealStateServlet: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: edu.uptc.model.Manager.findRealState(Ljava/lang/String;)Ledu/uptc/entity/RealState;

Comment: This error does not belong to the discussed code snippet. Check how you call the `RealState findRealState(RealStateID realStateId)` method

Comment: protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  RealStateID rsid = new RealStateID(request.getParameter("realStateAddressInput"),
    request.getParameter("realStateBlockInput"),Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("realStateInternalNumberInput")));
  Manager manager = new Manager();
  System.out.println(manager.findRealState(rsid).toString());
 }
I do it from the servlet, but I think I will do a different Question, Thanks a lot You've solved this inquiry

Comment: Ok The new problem seems to be fixed but, now Im getting the same:
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException Can't find realState for ID RealStateID [address=A302, block=A1, internal_id=302]
problem even with the overrided methods

Comment: will `em.createQuery("select rs FROM RealState rs").getResultList();` return any results?